# How is the full substring different from using .text()?

Tags: substring

I'm failing to see how taking the full substring is different from just using .text()?

This is a snippet of a larger code set that I'm trying to understand but failing:
$(this).text().substring(0, ($(this).text().length - 1))

Substring takes a portion of the full text/string, but in this case it is taking the whole string, correct?

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275733/what-is-jquery-doing)? 

Anyway, you have an answer :)

Comment: Damn Jacob, good catch. My previous question was a little more convoluted, so I thought if I broke it down it might help me understand the full deal piecemeal.

Comment: Hah yeah, I actually googled your exact snippet and the only other decent result was your other SO post.

Comment: I thought you had a freakishly good memory. I'm not so impressed anymore ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is returning characters 0 to *n*-1 of an *n* length string.

```
x = "hello";
>>> "hello"
x.substring(0, x.length - 1)
>>> "hell"
```

From the MDN documentation linked:

> substring extracts characters from indexA up to but not including indexB. In particular:
>
> - If indexA equals indexB, substring returns an empty string.
> - If indexB is omitted, substring extracts characters to the end of the string.
> - If either argument is less than 0 or is NaN, it is treated as if it were 0.
> - If either argument is greater than stringName.length, it is treated as if it were stringName.length.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. My memory must be failing. I didn't recall substring taking all but not including the last character.